# How to set custom Collection View Cell spacing for every cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cellspacing

I have a Collection View and I want to calculate the spacing between every single cell programmatically but I can't find out how to do this.

So, how can I calculate the inter-cells spacing between UICollectionViewCells in a UICollectionView with UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how you set custom cell spacing in a collectionview. You have to create an extension.

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return //whatever you want//

}
```

Make sure the "ViewController" that follows **extension** is the name of your viewcontroller.

Comment: I use this method to set the size of the cell but how can I set the inter cell spacing with this method?

Comment: What I personally do is return the size of the cell based on the screen size to get desired spacing between cells.

Comment: So to clarify, if the screen width is 300 and you want 2 cells per row with uniform 10 spacing (screen edge to cell, cell to cell, cell to screen edge), you would return 135 for the width portion of cell size. (300 - 10 - 10 - 10) / 2 = 135.